# How to Use a method in super class differently for subclasses ((without enum or any attributes))?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

The problem is that I want a super class of A and three subclasses , B,C,D.
and there's a method that only the super class A has , and none of the subclasses have that method and the method has different results in each sub class.
I also can't Override any methods.
how do I code this without using enum or giving any attributes to any class?
for example :

```
public class {
 public String method1(){
  //what each class type should do
 }
}
public class B extends{
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
   A[] elements = {new A(),new B()};
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(elements[i].method1());
 }
}
```

results eg:
    A1
    B1

Comment: Method overriding?

Comment: Why can't you override the `method1()` in each subclass.

Comment: you can't do this , you have to overriding the method or pass an enum or parameter

Comment: No I can't write any methods in any subclasses such as b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class A {
  public String method1() {
        if(this instanceof B) {
          return "Class B";
          //do something for class B
        } else if (this instanceof C) {
          return "Class C";
          //do something for class C
        }
        return "";
    }
}
class B extends A { }
class C extends A { }
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A[] elements = {new A(),new B()};
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
            System.out.println(elements[i].method1());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Method overriding is the best solution i think.

But if you want to have one function in class A, you can use istanceof to verify the class

if(object instnaceof A) doSomething ..

Comment: Can you explain how to idenify b.method using instnaceof ?

Comment: b.method() is going to call the class A method. Then it's going to check the type of the object b wich is an instance of B. So since b instanceof B is true it's going to execute the code specific for class B

Comment: i hope that answers your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use Generics like this, but better use overriding

```
 public class A {
        public <T extends A> String method1(T classInstance) {
            return method(classInstance);
       }

       private String method(A classInstance) {
            return classInstance.toString();
       }

       private String method(B classInstance) {
            return classInstance.toString();
       } 
}



 public class B extends A{
 }

 public class Application {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            A[] elements = {new A (), new B ()};
            for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println (elements[i].method1(elements[i]));
            }
        }
    }
```